# Why is my checkbox not connecting with my jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I really don't get why my check-box being clicked doesn't prompt my JS as well. I'll write the code and explain a little more in depth what's happening.

Here's my header (in-case I'm linking the wrong files):

```
<head>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='reset.css'/>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='Vector Add.css'/>
     <script src='Vector Add.js'></script>
</head>
```

Here's the checkbox itself:

```
<div id='gridButton'>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" value="showGrid"> Show Grid
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the first line of code for the table (The table is large and there's really no value in linking all that extra code):

```
<table id="gridTable" style="position:absolute">
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#gridCheck').is(':checked')===true){
        $('#gridTable').show('fast');
    } else {
        $('#gridTable').hide('fast');
    };
});
```

Essentially I have this graph and I want the user to be able to generate a grid whenever they click the "Show Grid" check-box and for it to go away when the check-box isn't selected. But for some reason it's not working. There are no errors but when I bring up the dev tool it's showing that the JS isn't realizing whether or not the buttons being clicked. I don't know what to do as I've been grappling with this for the past couple hours and nothing seems to work. Please help out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're checking if the box is checked when the page is loaded, not when the user checks it

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: also the `$('#gridCheck').is(':checked')===true` is redundant, you could just write `$('#gridCheck').is(':checked')` in the if() statement

Comment: you need to bind that within a function and call that function as event listener. Bind it on "onclick" function.

Comment: JavaScript. It's called JavaScript. It's not "java script" or "java-script" or "JAVAScript" or... Why do people have so much trouble with this?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I vote for *Javascript*. Why oh why are we supposed to bumpy case `JavaScript` and then wonder why newbies get confused by the apparent emphasis on **Java*Script*. BUT, I digress.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Hey, it wasn't up to *me*. :-) It was Netscape's decision (with [Sun's blessing](https://web.archive.org/web/20080208124612/http://wp.netscape.com/comprod/columns/techvision/innovators_be.html), interestingly) circa 1995. Talk about a bad call...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Hey, this is my facile resistance. *¡Viva la Revolución!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the `click` event to the checkbox so it is triggered on every check on and off.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#gridCheck').on('click', function(){    
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
         $('#gridTable').show('fast');
      } else {
         $('#gridTable').hide('fast');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: You could also do `if (this.checked)`, jQuery isn't really necessary there.

Comment: The `click` event is not the right one for the task, use the `change` event instead. It has much more direct relation to the state of the checkbox. a `label` element might also trigger the change.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't even know how I forgot that! Thank you!

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: A click on the label will fire a click on the checkbox related to it. http://jsbin.com/dusilegu/1 It used to be, with a small number of older browsers, that `change` didn't fire if the checkbox didn't lose focus (e.g., you tab to it and use the spacebar). I just tried with IE8 (the oldest IE I have handy) and modern Chrome and Firefox, and `change` fired without focus loss, so that may now be historical (thankfully). But that's why you see people using `click` for this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I stand corrected, the click event does seem to fire properly at all times. Yet I'm in favour of using the appropriate events for what is actually happening. You're not interested in the click, you want the moment that the value changes. What if in the future, a user can change the checkbox value by issuing a voice command, e.g. on a mobile device? `click` will probably break, `change` will not.

Answer (score 3):

Why watch clicks when you can watch `change`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gridCheck').on('change', function(){
        $('#gridTable').fadeToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

First, default the checkbox to be CHECKED if the grid will be displayed on page load:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" value="showGrid" checked/> Show Grid
```

Comment: @user3758172 -- [Accept] no substitutes; THIS is the Answer ;)  Here's proof: http://jsfiddle.net/rodgolpe/La7tN/